# Phrasing of Age Eligibility section of the Terms of Service

Tags: discussion, terms-of-service

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.

The Stack Overflow [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age) specifies that users must be at least 13 years old (16 in the European Union) in order to use the website. **This question is not about whether such a requirement should exist or needs to exist; I am well aware of the reasoning and legal issues surrounding this, e.g. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61770/why-cant-i-use-stack-exchange-if-im-under-13-years-old-or-if-im-under-16-yea).** This question is about a particular concern regarding the way the requirement is stated:

> If you are under 13 years old, you may not, under any circumstances or for any reason, **access or use** the Services or Network in any manner, and may not provide any personal information to or on the Services or Network (including, for example, a name, address, telephone number or email address).

(Emphasis added.) The problem is that the words "access" and "use" applies not only to account-owning users who actively give personal information to the site in order to register, but to anyone who *views even a single page on the https://stackoverflow.com domain*. Arguably, this even includes the terms of service page itself, so by the time an underage user finds out about the age requirement, they have already broken the Terms. Even if we don't consider viewing the Terms as accessing the site, in order to reach the Terms of Service, a user has to go through **at the very least** either the Stack Overflow homepage or a link to the site (such as a search result), unless they, say, search for the Terms of Service page directly before visiting any Stack Overflow page, which is extreme even for a very legally-cautious user. I know this is quite an extreme interpretation, but we should be careful dealing with legal issues like this, right?

It is theoretically possible (although exceedingly unlikely) that in the United States, this could have criminal implications for the underage user; see [this Electronic Frontier Foundation article](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2013/04/are-you-teenager-who-reads-news-online-according-justice-department-you-may-be).

How do we deal with this issue without breaking COPPA and GDPR? Maybe we should specify that users under 13 (or 16) cannot register on the site, without forbidding all access. I'm not confident though that a mere visitor to the site who does not register or post does not give any personal information in the sense of COPPA/GDPR. Apparently, even browser cookies and IP addresses could count, according to [part C.5 of the FTC COPPA FAQ](https://www.ftc.gov/business-guidance/resources/complying-coppa-frequently-asked-questions#C.%20Privacy%20Policies). Thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

Not a lawyer, but old enough to know a thing or two about this.

Ultimately this law is intended to prevent the *intentional* capturing of data from users who are not of age in their respective country (16 in EU, 13 most everywhere else).

**No site can actively verify what age you *actually* are without requiring a lot of PII.**  This is more or less to stipulate that that site does not knowingly collect information about persons below that age in their respective jurisdiction, and it allows them to act quickly to remove that data should they need to.

I think a long time ago a long-standing member of the community had to have their account deleted because it violated one of these policies when they created it, which...sucks, but beats being in violation of the law.